# Converting PDF to Image in PHP with imagick (CPANEL APACHE WORDPRESS LINUX)

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick

An error when occurs converting a PDF file with multiple pages, into multiple images (as separate jpg files). The error log shows the imagick **error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image 'https://====PATH TO FILE===.pdf page 1 of 1.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496 in ====PATH TO FILE===/Custom.php:64
Stack trace:
#0 ====PATH TO FILE====/Custom.php(64): Imagick->writeimage('https://portal....')
```

I am running **PHP 7.4** for a **WordPress** installation, utilizing **CPANEL** & **Apache** on a **Linux** server.

Could someone advice how I should solve this in the context of my environment?

PHP script:

```
//$Posted_Media is the filepath in the format (https://... .pdf)//

    $Formatted_PDF = new imagick($Posted_Media);
    $Number_of_Pages = $Formatted_PDF->getNumberImages();
    $Resolution = 600;

    $imagick = new imagick();
    $imagick->setResolution($Resolution, $Resolution);
    $imagick->readImage($Posted_Media);
    $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
         
         foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) { 
         $imagick->writeImage($Posted_Media. " page ". ($i+1) ." of ".  $Number_of_Pages.".jpg"); 
          }

    $imagick->clear();
```